# Java - Hibernate Tools Query property should be explicitly set for Query Exporter?

Tags: java, hibernate

i learn Hibernate by follow step [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/).

But I got this error:

> Query property should be explicitly set for Query Exporter

when run Hibernate Code Generation( The last step). Do anyone know it?

[image: Here is Image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Don't select "HQL Query Execution Exporter" in "Hibernate Code Generation Configuration" "Exports" tab.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud set the reveng.xml file.
In the Hibernate Generate Code Configuration window, click the Setup button at the "reveng.xml" line.

Then choose "Create new...", select the location for the configuration file you will create.
Click "refresh", you will see your schema so you can choose what table you want to reverse engineer.
I do not have enough reputation to post screenshots, I am sorry.
I hope this helps.